# IdentityServer directly logout redirection to a page

Tags: identityserver3

I have an IdentityServer options to redirect without signout propt.

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions    
     {
          // other options ....
          AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
          {
              EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
              EnableSignOutPrompt = false, 
          }
     };
```

When I logout, the system redirects me to an identityserver page that has a message like this "you are logout.". but this page appears very short time and I am redirecting to login page fast. Can I skip this identity server page while logout?

My logout controller like this.

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        if (Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:33125/"
            };

            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(properties);
        }

        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html

`AuthenticationOptions` has a `EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect` and a `PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay` setting.

Beware if you set this to auto redirect after too short a period of time, your single signout might not be completed to the other apps the user has signed into.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have covered all the steps from the documentation for this part of IdentityServer's configuration. `PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay` already is defaulting to 0. So it won't get a quicker redirect back to the origin URL.

I don't think there is a way to skip the page altogether, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In IdentityServer4, the `Logout` method of the `AccountController` can be modified so that it returns a redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    ...

    return Redirect("http:// client url"); // added

    //return View("LoggedOut", vm); // commented out
}
```

Yes, it is custom code, it is a quick solution.

Comment: I could only get it to work with my set up using this approach, thank you.